# Is it possible to fire a single intent multiple times?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

I have a service that does database calls.  The service receives a request with an intent, and when the database call is complete, it broadcasts an "update complete" intent indicating the completion of the call.

Sometimes the database is already populated with cached data, in which case I would like to immediately broadcast an "update complete" intent, indicating the activity should display the cached data, and then once the database has been updated fire another "update complete" intent indicating the activity should load the updated data.

The problem is that the second broadcast is never received by the activity.  Is this because I'm re-using the same intent object that has already been fired?

Here's the code:

```
if (scheduleDatabase.populated()) {
    intent.putExtra("fromCache", true);
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
}

scheduleDatabase.update();
intent.putExtra("fromCache", false);
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

An update:
If I comment out one of the intent broadcasts, the other one always fires and is received.
Also, if I create two intent objects with the same action string and fire them separately, only the first one is ever received by the activity.  I'm not clear yet on whether the other gets fired but not received, or if it never fires at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the problems I had with the intents were a symptom of a larger problem in a different area of my code.  After fixing that problem, the intents began firing and receiving as I expected.  So, to answer my own original question, yes it is possible to fire a single intent multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. Yes the second intent is overwriting the first one. My workaround was to create a new Intent in my BroadcastReceiver. You have access to the same context, and can pass data in the extras.

Comment: I'm not sure why I would want to create an intent in the receiver.  Maybe you can give me more details about your workaround?  Also, the first intent is always received and the second intent is not.  I don't see how that would happen if the second is overwriting the first.

Comment: In my case I'm creating a new alarm with AlarmManger based on information passed from the previous alarm. I have a table of countdown timers. I pass the time of the previous alarm in the extras so that I can grab the next alarm from the table. I can then fire the intent with AlarmManager, or in your case at that moment.